# How to cut original array without copying

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how can I work with the array that has been passed in constructor without copying it. I'm working with indexers and the task is to get a subarray of original array. Here is my code:

```
`public class Indexer
    {
        public double this[int index]
        {
            get { return array[index]; }
            set { array[index] = value; }
        }

        double[] array;

        public int Length { get { return array.Length; } }

        public Indexer(double[] array,int start,int length)
        {
            if (start < 0 || length<0 || array.Length-start<length) throw new ArgumentException();          
            this.array = array.ToList().GetRange(start, length).ToArray();
        }
    }`
```

At the moment it just copies the original array and creates new subarray. I know it might be an easy question, but I really can't figure out how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: ... `Span<T>` if you can use it

Comment: @MichaelRandall Hence why I asked what version :)

Comment: If you can't use `Span<T>` then use [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: whats preventing you from just using the array passed in the constructor directly. You dont need to copy it, just use it.

Comment: If you used a List object it would be passed by reference and then you do not need to copy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're reinventing the wheel. You should be able to use `ArraySegment<T>` instead of `class Indexer`.

Comment: [Take a look](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9808f1f5ef16c436) on how Microsoft solves the problem, if a new add exceeds the current size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save start and length, then you can index the sub-array without copy.

```
public class Indexer
{
    int start, length;
    double[] array;

    public double this[int index]
    {
        get { CheckIndex(index); return array[start + index]; }
        set { CheckIndex(index); array[start + index] = value; }
    }

    public int Length { get { return length; } }

    private void CheckIndex(int index)
    {
        if(index < 0 || index >= length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException('index');
    }

    public Indexer(double[] array,int start,int length)
    {
        if (start < 0 || length<0 || array.Length-start<length) throw new ArgumentException();          
        this.array = array;
        this.start = start;
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

BTW, ArraySegment has already done the job.

Comment: Thanks you! That's exactly what I've been looking for. And about ArraySegment, that is what my task actually is! :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it's working..
I am not sure what you are looking for,

But i am assuming that you want to get the result array from Indexer Class.

See the below code,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] d=new double[7]{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0};
        var inx=new Indexer(d,1,3);
        foreach(var i in inx.array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("d.LEn="+inx.array.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
    public class Indexer
    {
        public double this[int index]
        {
            get { return array[index]; }
            set { array[index] = value; }
        }

        public double[] array;

        public int Length { get { return array.Length; } }

        public Indexer(double[] array,int start,int length)
        {
            if (start < 0 || length<0 || array.Length-start<length) throw new ArgumentException();          
            this.array = array.ToList().GetRange(start, length).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```